Миграция консольного Windows-приложения в облако
Миграция десктопного windows приложения в облако.
Нужно разместить приложение в облаке и запускать его программным запросом через интернет.
Есть fo.exe  - простейшая десктопная консольная  программа для x86 windows с набором dll в папке. При загрузке в компьютер установка не требуется, поскольку все необходимые dll загружаются в ту же папку.
При запуске, программа fo.exe читает файл с фиксированным именем tx1.txt и выдает результат в файл result.txt. Никакого оконного интерфейса не используется.
Есть облако Vscale.io с установленным сервером microsoft windows server 2012.
Мне нужно выполнить действия:

загрузить в облако приложение fo.exe;
программным образом загрузить текстовый файл исходных данных;
запустить программу из интернета;
считать результирующий файл result.txt  из облака.
Подскажите, какие надо сделать основные действия.
Доступ к серверу у меня есть через подключение к удаленному рабочему столу.


в windows server думаю есть sshd, он даже в pro есть, пользуйтесь ssh

Добавлю, что есть ещё WinRM. Но ssh конечно круче.
